# How to have a child component place a component (button) in the Parent

Tags: reactjs

I have a react SPA in which various pages inherit from a `Page` component.

`Page` defines a common help button in the top-right of the page, which is fine so far, except that some child components want to put their own buttons at the top-right so these appear below the top-level, wasting vertical space.

[image]

I tried using an `Outlet` to represent a button that the child might want to place in the "toolbar", but it killed the page. There's also no google results for doing such a thing, so I might be on the wrong track.

Parent.jsx

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const [button1, setButton1] = React.useState();

  return (
    <div className="Page">
      <Outlet context={button1} />
      <HelpButton />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child.jsx

```
const AuthorisationPage = () => {
const [setButton1] = useOutletContext();
setButton1(<button onClick={addNewUser}>Add new user</button>);
return (
  <Page>
    <div className="AuthorisationPage">
      <div className="rbac-user-role-grid">
        <Grid ...
```

Comment: Have you considered composition over inheritance? With that, the state pattern will be your best friend. Ps: it will lead to a little code restructuring.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use state with the button name and conditional render the buttons, actions, and texts in the parent?